# Where can I download the drivers for a Canon MP 420 Series?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I'm trying to set up a Canon MP 420 Series printer on Ubuntu 11.10, but for some reason the wizard can't find the corresponding drivers. I looked for the drivers in  , but they are not there. Even though the printer appears as installed and functioning, I cannot print with it form Ubuntu. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Often you can find printer drivers for Linux at http://www.openprinting.org/printers, but I don't see any "MP 420" there. I also don't see any Canon "MP 420" on the official site though, so perhaps that isn't the model name? It'd be worth a check.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming in this answer that you have made a typo - possibly you are asking for the MX420 series drivers or the MP240 drivers.

There is a PPA which you can install to add these drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon  
sudo apt-get update
```

Then for the MX420:

```
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mx420series
```

For the MP240:

```
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp240series
```

More information can be found on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon).